# How to convert base64 mpeg to AudioClip in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, base64, mp3, audioclip

After some research, I have got the following

```
private float[] Normalize(float[] data)  {
    float max = float.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++){
        if (System.Math.Abs(data[i]) > max) max = System.Math.Abs(data[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) data[i] = data[i] / max;
    return data;
}

private float[] ConvertByteToFloat(byte[] array){
    float[] floatArr = new float[array.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++){
        if (System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)  System.Array.Reverse(array, i * 4, 4);
        floatArr[i] = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(array, i * 4) ;
    }
    return Normalize(floatArr);
}
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data);
float[] f = ConvertByteToFloat(bytes);
qa[i] = AudioClip.Create("qjAudio", f.Length, 2, 44100, false);
qa[i].SetData(f,0);
```

However, all I heard was some random noise.

How can I correctly convert a base64 mp3 string into AudioClip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some reseach and come up that [UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip.html) is way to go.

1. Convert your base64 string into byte array
   `var audioBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedMp3String);`
2. Create temp path to store it as reference
   `var tempPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "tmpMP3Base64.mp3";`
3. Write all bytes to that path
   `File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, audioBytes);`
4. Use UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip to read from that path
   `UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(tempPath, AudioType.MPEG);`

Here is a complete example:

```
[SerializeField] private AudioSource _audioSource;
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ConvertBase64ToAudioClip(EXAMPLE_BASE64_MP3_STRING, _audioSource));
}
        
IEnumerator ConvertBase64ToAudioClip(string base64EncodedMp3String, AudioSource audioSource)
{
    var audioBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedMp3String);
    var tempPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "tmpMP3Base64.mp3";
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, audioBytes);
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(tempPath, AudioType.MPEG);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.result.Equals(UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError))
        Debug.LogError(request.error);
    else
    {
        audioSource.clip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(request);
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    File.Delete(tempPath);
}
```

Comment: Marvellous! I can get it working on my PC Unity Editor. Do you think it will work on an Android device or WebGL?

Comment: Great it helped and yes it should work on all platforms with only difference will be persistentDataPath will vary for each platform but it will work.